# Create Ansible variables for username and password with special characters

Tags: variables, ansible

I have my vcenter username "Administrator@vsphere.local" and password as "Test@2100$1", if I create variable as below:

```
  vars:
    - username: 'vsphere.local\Administrator'
  vars_prompt:
    - name: password
      prompt: Enter Vcenter password to authenticate fence user
```

It authenticates with wrong username and password, when checked in the configuration it shows:
username = vsphere.localAdministrator {without the slash}
password = Test@2100 {without the $1 characters in the password text}.

Kindly suggest me how to key in the AD domain username "vsphere.local\Administrator" and password with special character as ansible variable.

Comment: you dont show how you try to authenticate, the problem is here not with the content of variables username and password which accept all characters...

Comment: but the password character "$1" is not visible in the file. Can you please suggest how can I ensure all characters are incorporated in the configuration.

Comment: what do you mean by file, you dont show any tasks, ....

Answer (score 0):

so a simple test to check the value off user/password:
i have added *private: no* to see the password typed

```
- name: test 
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    username: vsphere.local\Administrator   
  vars_prompt:
    - name: password
      prompt: Enter Vcenter password to authenticate fence user 
      private: no    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: password for {{ username }} is {{ password}}
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: password for vsphere.local\Administrator is Test@2100$1
```

Comment: any options to have the password include all special characters without using private: no

Comment: i dont understant, whatever the value of private yes or no, the result is same??

Comment: Password text I have key-in ="Test@2100$1" but what I get is "Test@2100"

Comment: with @ i have the same result, no problem